# Internal Filtering in Solr

Tags: node.js, mongodb, solr, lucene

I have just recently integrated Solr into my nodejs/mongodb application to handle the more advanced querying of a specific collection in my service. I have used the mongo-connector to synchronize my mongodb with the Solr database and customized the Solr fields to bring in the necessary fields to query on.

There is a `visible` property of a document in this collection that we use to determine whether the object is public (seen by all) or private (seen by owner). Prior to using Solr, we had server API calls that handled ensuring the `visible` bit came into play on requests, but now I am unsure how to mimic the functionality in Solr.

Our intention is to his Solr directly from the client app using Solr's query parameters with our client-side search/filter page. Is there a way to ensure that all calls to Solr get appended with a filter saying `visible = true` in order to ensure private documents are not included in the response? I don't want to have to write it from the client side, because this still exposes these documents.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the only way to filter out results from solr is to use the fq parameter along with your query but if you are not inclined towards appending it, you could always index the private and public docs to 2 separate cores and then just serve the results from one or the other based on the user,=.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add a parameter list to a definition for a requestHandler that appends a `fq` statement to all requests. [The example from the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration) solves an identical use case:

```
<lst name="appends">
  <!-- no matter what other fq are also used, always restrict to only inStock products -->
  <str name="fq">inStock:true</str>
</lst>
```